# Pass array to excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a formula like this

```
SUMIFS(CURR_COUNT;MDL;"ALT";MDLCD;{13117;13417};RG;"44";CURR_OPTION_GROUP;"**")
```

And I need to split string from cell and pass array to formula instead of `{13117;13417}` 
I can parse string in VBA for example or maybe in excel but I do not know how to pass it to formula.

I have wrote this peace of code in VBA

```
Function GetArray(str) As Variant
    GetArray = Split(str, ",")
End Function
```

And add to formula

```
CURR_COUNT;MDL;"ALT";CURR_MDLCD;GetArray(BF22);RG;"44";CURR_OPTION_GROUP;"**")
```

But it use only firs element of the array.

Comment: You need to wrap the sumifs in SUM(...) for it to do both..

Comment: I did this but it did not help me
`SUM(SUMIFS(CURR_COUNT;MDL;"ALT";MDLCD;GetArray(BF22);RG;"44";CURR_OPTION_GROUP;"**"))`

Comment: Basically I need to pass data to sumifs criteria. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your customized function for doing this eg

```
Function rangetoarray(rng as range) 
     i=""
     For each cell in rng
          i=i&";"&cell
     Next
  rangetoarray=i
End Function
```

and then use this within you sumif function and check whether its working or not

Comment: Point is that I have data on one cell not range. And data of cell = "13117,13417" for example. I need to parse this data and set it to formula instead of hard coded data.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula as `FormulaArray`:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(CURR_COUNT;MDL;"ALT";MDLCD;GetArray(BF22);RG;"44";CURR_OPTION_GROUP;"**"))
```

*FormulaArrays are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*